# GIT: Problemas com conflitos quando há espaço em branco

Tags: git

Não sei o que está acontecendo com o repositório que eu estou usando, mas todos os programadores que estão utilizando ele estão contemplando os mesmos conflitos depois do `pull`.

E muitas vezes esse conflitos estão sendo ocasionados por simples espaços que são adicionados ou retirados no documento.

Exemplo:

```
public function get(){

    <<< HEAD


    ========
    3423asdasd023423>>>>>

    $test = 1;
    return $test;
  }
```

Como posso resolver isso?

Comment: Isto está com cara de corrupção de arquivo. E é claro que foi propagando para todo mundo.

Comment: Ficar dando `chmod -R 0777 *` na pasta clone do repositório pode ocasionar esse problema? (visto que parece contar como uma alteração, de acordo como `rabbitvcs`?

Comment: Será que não pode ser esses comandos do `java -jre bfg` e `git filter-branch` que está dando esses paus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao dar um `git merge`, você pode ignorar as verificações nos espaços em branco usando o seguinte parâmetro:

```
git merge -Xignore-all-space
```

ou

```
git merge -Xignore-space-change
```